# Rewrite this URL with parameter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having problems understanding the rewriting rules. Basically what I am trying to do is change this:

http://domain.com/Intern/guangjian/gallery/?page=admin_login

Into this:

http://domain.com/Intern/guangjian/gallery/admin_login

I keep getting 500 Internal Server Error when I applied various rules to my .htaccess file. Please help. Currently I have the below:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^/%2
```

I admit I don't really understand what all the symbols mean.

Comment: Is `/Intern/guangjian/gallery/` a real directory?

Comment: By real you mean accessible? Yes it is.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols are converting the characters into a sequence of bytes in a specific set using character encoding

Example

Original URL.
Eg. http://flickr.com/users.php?id=username&page=2

Rewriting Friendly URL.
Eg. http://flickr.com/username/2

//First Parameter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ users.php?user=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ users.php?user=$1
```

//Second Parameter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)/$ users.php?user=$1&page=$2
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesnt work:
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ ?page=$1`

Answer (score 0):

Place this code in `/Intern/guangjian/gallery/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Intern/guangjian/gallery/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ ?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Rewrite Rule** syntax is: *RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]*.

This means only the flags (L, NC, R, etc...) are optional, the pattern to match and the substitution parts are mandatory. But you only specified one, which is why you are getting a 500 Internal Server Error.

You don't need RewriteCond. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?(\w+)=(\w+)$ $1/$3
```

You are getting everything up to the **?**, and then attaching the value of *page*, or whatever argument of the query string, to the url. This of course only works when you have only one argument in the query string, the regex won't match in other case.